# Person with Multiple Addresses

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to create a Create page for a slightly complex 'view model'/view setup that I'm looking for.

Imagine I have two entities -

Person

-PersonID

-Name

-Height

-Nationality

And that Person can have multiple Addresses - here's the Address entity:

Address

-PersonID

-AddressDescriptor

-FirstLine

-SecondLine

-City

-ZipCode

Now in my Person Create view I want the user to be able to enter the person details,
and then add as many addresses as they like.
I'm visualizing this as something like a set of text boxes for both the person and the address area.  Followed by an add button for the address.  When clicked this add button would add the address to a grid of added addresses.  The grid would also have options for delete/edit.

Finally there would be a submit button to save the person and address records to the database.

What is my best bet for achieving something like this.
Should I be looking to use partial views for the grid / rendered by AJAX calls back to the controller?  If so could someone point me to a modern example of doing this - using Razor if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This runs through the basic principles of what you are trying to achieve:

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/

Comment: Thanks - much appreciated.  This helped me to rephrase my search and I found the following http://ivanz.com/2011/06/16/editing-variable-length-reorderable-collections-in-asp-net-mvc-part-1/

I think between all of these examples I should be able to do what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You could create an action that accepts AJAX posts to add the user.  Just create a jQuery function that will create your form when they click "add address" and on submit, another jquery ajax call to post to your controller action.

Comment: Good ideas.  I think I'll be combining them with the answer below.